# how to replace values by comparing two columns in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looks like:

```
df<-read.table(text="ID           RE          AL 
140343         TC           T
200012      A       G
457096        GAA        GAAA
555084         AG           A
557151          T         TAA
752311   GAATTAAT        GAAT
810001     ATTTTT       ATTTT
880420 GAAAAAAAAA GAAAAAAAAAA", header=TRUE, colClasses="character")
```

I would like to replace the longer string in column "RE" or "AL" with letter "I", and the shorter one replaced with letter "D". if both columns have one letter, no change.

the expected result:

```
ID      RE  AL
140343  I   D
200012  A   G
457096  D   I
555084  I   D
557151  D   I
752311  I   D
810001  I   D
880420  D   I
```

I tried my script as:

```
max <- apply(df[2:3], 1, function(x) max(nchar(x)))
index <- max > 1
if(nchar(df$RE[index])==max[index]){
  df$RE[index] <- "I"
  df$AL[index] <- "D"
}else{
  df$RE[index] <- "D"
  df$AL[index] <- "I"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A base R vectorized solution. First line defines a subset of rows to work on. Then two lines with opposite directions for the comparison lets you choose either "D" or "I" based on the comparisons:

```
noneq <- with( df, (nchar(RE) != 1)|( nchar(AL) != 1) )
df[ noneq, "RE"] <- with(df[ noneq, ], c("D","I")[1+(nchar(RE) > nchar(AL) )])
df[ noneq, "AL"] <- with(df[ noneq, ], c("D","I")[1+(RE=="D" )])  # opposite of RE

df
#==============
      ID RE AL
1 140343  I  D
2 200012  A  G
3 457096  D  I
4 555084  I  D
5 557151  D  I
6 752311  I  D
7 810001  I  D
8 880420  D  I
```

Comment: @Jaap: Thanks your your corrections, but why delete your answer? I saw the 2 indexing strategies as complementary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution that may work for you

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(RE = ifelse(nchar(RE) != 1 | nchar(AL) != 1,
                       ifelse(nchar(RE) > nchar(AL), 'I', 'D'), RE),
           AL = ifelse(RE=='I', 'D', ifelse(RE=='D', 'I', AL)))

##       ID RE AL
## 1 140343  I  D
## 2 200012  A  G
## 3 457096  D  I
## 4 555084  I  D
## 5 557151  D  I
## 6 752311  I  D
## 7 810001  I  D
## 8 880420  D  I
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple for loop that gets the job done:

```
for (i in seq(1:nrow(df))){
    if(nchar(df[i, 3]) - nchar(df[i, 2]) < 0){
        df[i, 3] <- "D"
        df[i, 2] <- "I"
    }else if(nchar(df[i, 3]) - nchar(df[i, 2]) > 0){
        df[i, 3] <- "I"
        df[i, 2] <- "D"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative base R solution (compareble to @42- 's answer, but with pre-defining the indexes):

```
# create needed indexes
idx1 <- !(nchar(df$RE) == 1 & nchar(df$AL) == 1)
idx2 <- (nchar(df$RE) > nchar(df$AL)) + 1L
idx3 <- (nchar(df$RE) < nchar(df$AL)) + 1L

# replace the values
df$RE[idx1] <- c('D','I')[idx2][idx1]
df$AL[idx1] <- c('D','I')[idx3][idx1]
```

which gives:

```
> df
      ID RE AL
1 140343  I  D
2 200012  A  G
3 457096  D  I
4 555084  I  D
5 557151  D  I
6 752311  I  D
7 810001  I  D
8 880420  D  I
```